# Patch Decorator with Side Effect: Issue with Raised Exception

Tags: python, exception, python-unittest, patch

Both the decorators I tried works in a sense as it does hit side_effect but I am getting the raised exception in my unittest though which makes it fail. What can I do? Code below:

```
# @patch('src.dao.dao.get_connection', ** {'return_value.raiseError.side_effect': Exception()})
@patch('src.dao.dao.get_connection', side_effect=my_foo())
def test_create_request(self, mock_conn):
    mock_conn.return_value = self.conn
    mock_cur = self.conn.cursor()
    mock_eid = 'to'
    mock_amount = 'throw'
    mock_message = 'an exception'
    try:
        mock_cur.execute("insert into reimbursements values(default, ?, ?, ?, 'pending', '')",
                     (mock_eid, mock_amount, mock_message))
        mock_conn.commit()
    finally:
        mock_conn.close()
```

Error below after `unittest` run:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\M\scoop\apps\python39\current\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 1337, in patched
return func(*newargs, **newkeywargs)
File "C:\Users\M\PycharmProjects\Project 1\tests\test_dao.py", line 47, in test_create_request
mock_cur.execute("insert into reimbursements values(default, ?, ?, ?, 'pending', '')",
pyodbc.DataError: ('22P02', '[22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for type money: "throw";\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Comment: It depends on what `self.conn` is, but it looks like it is not mocked.

Comment: It’s mocked in setUp. When I put in the correct data format then everything is fine but I want to raise an exception because create request function doesn’t return anything for unittesting.

Comment: So do you expect the exception? It's still not clear to me what you are mocking in `setUp`, and what is the expected outcome. Maybe you can show the relevent part of `setUp`?

Comment: def setUp(self):
        self.conn = connect(
            "DRIVER=PostgreSQL UNICODE(x64);SERVER=localhost;PORT=5432;DATABASE=postgres;UID=postgres;Trusted_Connection=no")

Comment: it's only one line but the issue is how to i catch a specific postgres sql exception

Comment: So you want to check for an expected exception? Why not use `assertRaises` then? Maybe I still don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: it's for unittest

Comment: Obviously it's for unittest - my question was, if you expect this exception (in which case you would use [assertRaises](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html?highlight=assertraises#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)).